# In CQ5, my responsive emulator devices list is empty

Tags: aem

To start, I followed these directions exactly as it's stated: http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/developing/mobile/responsive.html

The problem is, despite all of that, my Devices dropdown on the sidekick in preview mode is empty.

The list works without issue in the Geometrixx Media without issue.

I made sure I set the cq:deviceGroups and the sling:OsgiConfig as required, and also included the simulator.js in the head tags.

Edit: I have found that if I set the resourceType on the root level page to geometrixx-media/components/page, which is their working demo, it works.  I have completely removed all jsp and config items from that component page and it still continues to work anyways.

Does anyone know of something that is missing from the documents, and how to fix the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to resolve this issue:

I am going to assume your application name is `jason-riis`

In **CRXDE|Lite** create a `config` folder in `/apps/jason-riis/`

Now create a node of:

```
TYPE=sling:OsgiConfig
NAME=com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.MobileEmulatorProvider-<*alias>
```

> *alias could be anything, I gave my application name. What it does is it will get you a unique PID when you look at it in configuration Manager

If you go to your configuration manager now, you should be able to see two `MobileEmulatorProvider` config settings.

Add a node property to node you just created:

```
NAME=mobile.resourceTypes
TYPE=String[] (you have to click multi at the end of the value textbox)
VALUE=jason-riis/components/<*page>
```

> *page is all the components that has `sling:resourceSuperType` of `foundation/components/page` and it is a multi array so it should look like this

`jason-riis/components/page, jason-riis/components/widepage, jason-riis/components/newspage`

I assume you already have the `cq:include` for simulation in your header. This makes the devices button appear in preview mode.

Last thing is, go to your website root page's jcr:content [`/content/jason-riis/jcr:content`] and add node property

```
NAME=cq:deviceGroups
TYPE=String[]
*VALUE=/etc/mobile/groups/touch, /etc/mobile/groups/smart
```

> *If you go to this etc path in **CRXDE|Lite**; you will see more relevant information in `jcr:content` node. This will help you in creating your own custom emulator list.

You should be able to see the dropdown now, with options of iPhone and iPad and all. I know AEM docs are frustrating, let me know if there is any confusion.

Comment: Isn't this the same as stated in https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/mobile/responsive.html#Previewing%20for%20Specific%20Devices ?

Comment: It is not exactly the same, but part of it is true, if you have an understanding of it, you don't have to touch CRX, You can create the nodes in your development environment and make it a part of your bundle. I do my development in Netbeans